# Module compiled with Swift 5.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3.2 compiler:

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

[EROR IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVfLf.png)

Hello, I have a project in Flutter. I had to compile this project in Xcode. Say I got an error. I don't know Swift. How can I solve it in the shortest way? Thanks in advance to all of you.

Error output:

```
Module compiled with Swift 5.1.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.3.2 compiler: /Users/mbp/Documents/Tuccarim-proje/tuccarim-client-develop/ios/Pods/Publitio/Publitio.framework/Modules/Publitio.swiftmodule/x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
```

Comment: Xcode Version 12.4

Comment: I wish you would give an answer AMK.